# Problems with mfplain

Tags: fonts, metapost, metafont

When I read the file mfplain into Metapost, I get about a dozen error messages complaining about redundant and inconsistent equations. It's hard to believe that there is really anything wrong with mfplain. Any idea what might be going wrong ?

The details of the interaction are as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\miktex\bin>mpost
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (MiKTeX 2.9)
**\relax
(mpost.mp (C:/Program Files (x86)/MikTex/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004))
*\input mfplain
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MikTex/metapost/base/mfplain.mp
Preloading the plain base, version 0.99: preliminaries,
basic constants and mathematical macros,
macros for converting units,
! Inconsistent equation (off by 2.77794).
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.230 mm*bpppix_=2.83464;
                               pt*bpppix_=0.99626;
?
[[ followed by a dozen or so similar messages ]]
```

Comment: I don't think that `mfplain` is to be loaded when `plain.mp` is already loaded: they are designed for doing different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mfplain.mp` is designed to do very different things than `plain.mp`; if you want to build a Metafont as a Type3 font with Metapost, then something like

```
mpost -mem=mfplain cmr10.mf
```

will do.

Since version 1.5 (if I remember correctly), `mpost` doesn't really load `.mem` files any more, but it loads `plain.mp` by default. To get `mfplain.mp` in interactive mode, you can also call `mpost -ini`:

```bsh
egreg% mpost -ini
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
**mfplain
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mfplain.mp
Preloading the plain base, version 0.99: preliminaries,
 basic constants and mathematical macros,
 macros for converting units,
 macros and tables for various modes of operation,
 macros for drawing and filling,
 macros for proof labels and rules,
 macros for character and font administration,
and a few last-minute items.)
*
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought this might be the problem, but I couldn't figure out how to stop MetaPost loading mplain (or even determine if this was possible).

Comment: @bubba: You can probably also invoke it as just `mfplain`.